# How do you generate signed urls for google cloud storage objects in PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

First, let me tell you what i'm trying to accomplish...maybe there's an easier way than using signed urls with google cloud storage:

i want to upload files without public access to my bucket and when someone navigates to my server (that's not a google compute engine instance, but a regular cpanel machine) it should display the files just fine.

One way of doing it is through an url on my server that would download the file from google storage and serve it to the browser, but that's slow.

Another way that i've found was using these signed urls of google's. My problem would be: how do i generate them in PHP using the current APIs from google ?

I doubt it's of any importance but i'm using phalcon as my backend framework.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually working on implementing Signed URLs in Google Cloud PHP right now. I'm hoping to get it released this week or next: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/pull/536

Comment: Good news! With a little patience... i'll have a fix for my problem :)

Comment: @CApetrei Signed URL support has been added as of release 0.33.0: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/releases/tag/v0.33.0

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but i've been away on holidays and such. I tried using the library like this:
$object = $bucket->object('bla/DSCF8720_.jpg');
        if ($object->exists()) {
            $url = $object->signedUrl(new Timestamp(new \DateTime('tomorrow')), []);
        }
but when i paste the url in chrome, i get a SignatureDoesNotMatch error.